# Excel VBA for pivot Value using xlValueIsBetween

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I am trying to create a module to share functionality across a number of worksheets within a single workbook. All works fine apart from some filter code.

The code below works fine if I place it in a single worksheet

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MyField"). _
    ClearValueFilters
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MyField").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsBetween, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables _
    ("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MyValue"), Value1:=bottom, Value2:=Top
```

However, I want to use this code in my Module and send it the following:
 Pivot Table Name, 
Row PivotField, 
Value Pivot field
top "between" value
bottom "between" value

Something like:

The sheet call

```
Call Mod_Filter("PivotTable1", "MyRowFieldName", "MyValueFieldName", 0, intvalue)
```

The Module code

```
Public Sub Mod_Filter(ByRef PT_Name As String, ByRef StaticField As String, ByRef Filter_field As String, bottom As Double, Top As Double)
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PT_Name).PivotFields(StaticField).ClearValueFilters
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PT_Name).PivotFields(StaticField).PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsBetween, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables _
    (PT_Name).PivotFields(Filter_field), Value1:=bottom, Value2:=Top
End Sub
```

However, I cannot get this to work. Any suggestions??

[image]

So I'm using the "St" Row to filter the YTD% based on a value selected from a dropdown combo box

Comment: I think you need to replace Activesheet with the actual sheet object that contains the pivot (at the least).

Comment: Thanks @BobPhillips. I did try this, but still no joy!

Comment: I've also tried moving this sub into the Worksheet (rather than calling the Module) but this doesn't work either!

Comment: 1) Would you please confirm that the intent is to filter a `PivotField` based in another `PivotField`? If so please publish a picture of the PivotTable indicating the `PivotFields` involved, in order to increase your chances of getting a working solution. 2) Do you have worksheets with more than one `PivotTables`?

Comment: Many thanks @EEM. I've updated my question with a screenshot of the pivot. There are other worksheets in the workbook with data, but these only have single `PivotTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirement:**
To filter a Pivot `RowField` based on a Pivot `DataField`

This procedure uses the `PivotField.SourceName` to validate & set the `DataField` to apply the Filter Type and Values.

```
Sub Ptb_Filter_Between(WshTrg As Worksheet, _
    sFldTrg As String, sFldDta As String, dFromVal As Double, dToValue As Double)
Dim pTbl As PivotTable, pFldDta As PivotField

    Rem Application Settings - OFF
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Rem Set PivotTable
    'Using Index 1 as OP confirmed there is only one PivotTable per Sheet
    'If this condition change then PivotTable Index should be provided as an argument
    Set pTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    With pTbl

        Rem Set DataField - User provides the Data Field
        For Each pFldDta In .DataFields
            If pFldDta.SourceName = sFldDta Then Exit For
        Next
        If pFldDta Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitTkn

        Rem Filter PivotField
        .ClearAllFilters    'Use this line to clear all PivotTable Filters
        On Error GoTo ExitTkn
        With .PivotFields(sFldTrg)
            .ClearAllFilters    'This line clears all PivotField Filters
            .PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlValueIsBetween, _
                DataField:=pFldDta, Value1:=dFromVal, Value2:=dToValue
    End With: End With

ExitTkn:
    Rem Application Settings - ON
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

These are some samples of how to call the procedure:

```
sFldTrg = "Type"
sFldDta = "Amount"
dFromVal = 25000
dToValue = 30000
    Call Ptb_Filter_Between(Worksheet Object, sFldTrg, sFldDta, dFromVal, dToValue)

sFldTrg = "Type"
sFldDta = "YTD%"
dFromVal = 0.3
dToValue = 0.35
    Call Ptb_Filter_Between(Worksheet Object, sFldTrg, sFldDta, dFromVal, dToValue)

sFldTrg = "Row"
sFldDta = "YTD%"
dFromVal = 0.1  'To set from value as 10%
dToValue = 0.2  'To set to value as 20%
    Call Ptb_Filter_Between(Worksheet Object, sFldTrg, sFldDta, dFromVal, dToValue)
```

Comment: Many thanks @EEM. This works a treat in almost all cases! One complication I can't seem  to resolve though is where I create the calculated fields/Names within the script itself (during Worksheet Open). However, I can use my alternate code in these cases!

Comment: Glad it solved your issue, however it's strange what you reported about calculated fields. It should work with then as I tested with calculated fields as well. Check the `PivotField` name you are using...